# how to connect to Oracle 11g database using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

How do I connect to an Oracle 11g database using asp.net3.5?

what is the name space and how to write connection string in web.config file?

please help me..

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the data provider. See: [ConnectionString.com](http://connectionstrings.com/oracle) And perhaps more specifically: [The .NET Data Provider for Oracle](http://connectionstrings.com/oracle#p19). The connection string should look very similar in your web.config file. The only differences, obiously, will be the system/db name(s), user id, pwd etc.

[Namespaces](http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/04/object-namespaces-in-oracle.html):

> it is necessary to know which type of
>   objects can have the same name and
>   which are not. For this it is
>   necessary to introduce the concept of
>   a namespace. A namespace defines a
>   group of object types, within which
>   all names must be uniquely
>   identified—by schema and name. Objects
>   in different namespaces can share the
>   same name.

Here's also a [nice tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c8477/) you can follow that is ASP.NET-specific. And [another article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t080902-1.shtml) that may be of interest.

And a code snippet (using .NET Oracle provider:)

```
public DataTable myDataTable(string SQL, string ConnStr)
{
    OracleConnection cn = default(OracleConnection);
    DataSet dsTemp = null;
    OracleDataAdapter dsCmd = default(OracleDataAdapter);

    cn = new OracleConnection(ConnStr);
    cn.Open();

    dsCmd = new OracleDataAdapter(SQL, cn);
    dsTemp = new DataSet();
    dsCmd.Fill(dsTemp, "myQuery");
    cn.Close();
    return dsTemp.Tables[0];
}
```